# Create different drop down list for multiple columns using POI

Tags: java, excel, drop-down-menu, apache-poi, multiple-columns

How to create different drop down list in excel for multiple columns using POI? I've tried with the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
{

CellRangeAddressList addressList = 
new CellRangeAddressList(1,10,columnIndexFromHeaderList,columnIndexFromHeaderList);

DVConstraint dvConstraint = 
DVConstraint.createExplicitListConstraint(stringArray);
dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation(addressList,dvConstraint);                      
dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have not added the dataValidation in sheet... Please add it ... Hope this will work.

```
    {
       CellRangeAddressList addressList = 
       new CellRangeAddressList(1,10,columnIndexFromHeaderList,columnIndexFromHeaderList);
       DVConstraint dvConstraint = 
       DVConstraint.createExplicitListConstraint(stringArray);
       dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation(addressList,dvConstraint);                      
       dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
       sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation );

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I have added dataValidation.It is for single dropdown list,But I want different dropdown list for different columns.